# Cursor changes position in input line after I highlight some text to overwrite it

Tags: macos, keyboard, cursor

My problem is that when I highlight some text (doesn't matter where or in which application) in order to write over it the cursor, sometimes, suddenly changes position causing a lot of typos.

Let's say I've searched the phrase "stack exchange apple" in Google.

Now I want to search for stack overflow so I first highlight "exchange" and "apple" this way:

[image: highlighted stack exchange]

and then I simply type "overflow" in order to write over the highlighted text. What I sometimes end up with is this:

[image: wrong stack overflow]

And I can assure you that I didn't press any arrow keys or trackpad or mouse button of sort. I simply wrote in the keyboard "overflow" but what happened is that after I pressed "O" the cursor changed position and the word ended up like this.

I'm running macOS Sierra v10.12.4 on a Mid-2014 15" Macbook Pro

Are there things that can fail or settings to help with this?

Comment: Any chance your palms could be close to the trackpad? If it happens in all apps, all the time, a hardware repair might be needed. Tough to tell without seeing video of your setup in action  or being in the room as you type.

Comment: @bmike I know, it's a hard question to post online. I can assure you that my palms are not on the trackpad nor near it. in any case I just wanted to know if this could be a known bug and if there could be a fix for it. But form what you're saying it's probably better to bring the laptop to an Apple Store and see what they can do. Thank you.

Comment: Turn off autocorrect and see if it keeps happening.  I've encountered this problem, and it's just a bug in the latest OS update I believe

Comment: @StephenR Doesn't change anything

Comment: Can you reproduce this with an external keyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely culprit once you rule out Bluetooth mouse / trackpad and any wrist or liquid input is hardware.

If you can reproduce this on a clean os install onto an external drive (to avoid wiping your normal drive and files and apps) it could be:

- failing battery pressing underneath the trackpad
- failing or damaged capacitive sensing grid
- failing chip that processes the capacitive touch sensor

It's unlikely to be software, but I'd still download and install a clean and updated os to be sure unless you have close and easy access to hardware service.

Answer (score -1):

Same exact problem.  I'd be very surprised if this were a physical issue.  I have the same problem on two separate Macbook Pro's.  Also happens in multiple applications.  There's definitely no mousepad bumping either. 
 Unfortunately, the behavior difficult to reproduce.